# Need to extract words from a file before and after ^A in perl

Tags: perl, extract

I have many log files like `cancel_log1`,`cancel_log2`...

All files contains logs like this

```
2013/05/08 17:09:18 -0700 766 | 1368058158 | 22991 | yapache | cancelfeedback | INFO | File: /home/y/share/UNI/sites/order/cache/views/root:order:bucket=A:cancelservice:cache Function: () line: 450 Online^Atoo_expensive^AMoney is tight. I would to keep the service but I don&#39;t have the money at this time. Maybe I can come back in the future.^Asecuresanctuary.org^AWeb Hosting^Asecuresanctuary^A05/09/2009^A05/08/2013    
2013/05/07 17:45:35 -0700 219 | 1367973935 | 23388 | yapache | cancelfeedback | INFO | File: /home/y/share/UNI/sites/order/cache/views/root:order:bucket=A:cancelservice:cache Function: () line: 450 Online^Aother^AYahoo China service close^Alifesig.com^AWeb Hosting^Akennethli2005^A05/10/2008^A05/07/2013    
2013/05/08 17:30:57 -0700 115 | 1368059457 | 22982 | yapache | cancelfeedback | INFO | File: /home/y/share/UNI/sites/order/cache/views/root:order:bucket=A:cancelservice:cache Function: () line: 450 Online^Atoo_expensive^A^Asecuresanctuary.org^AWeb Hosting^Asecuresanctuary^A05/09/2009^A05/08/2013    
2013/05/07 17:59:38 -0700 694 | 1367974778 | 23381 | yapache | cancelfeedback | INFO | File: /home/y/share/UNI/sites/order/cache/views/root:order:cancelstep5:cache Function: () line: 436 Online^Amissing_feature^A^Achuanqisf244baidu.com^ADomains^Achuanqisf244baidu^A05/07/2013^A05/07/2013    
2013/05/08 17:33:03 -0700 815 | 1368059583 | 23000 | yapache | cancelfeedback | INFO | File: /home/y/share/UNI/sites/order/cache/views/root:order:cancelstep5:cache Function: () line: 436 Online^Aretired^A^Asisterthrifty.com^ADomains^Atrinaboice^A08/09/2005^A05/08/2013    
2013/05/07 17:59:40 -0700 231 | 1367974780 | 23389 | yapache | cancelfeedback | INFO | File: /home/y/share/UNI/sites/order/cache/views/root:order:cancelstep5:cache Function: () line: 436 Online^Amissing_feature^A^Achuanqisf239baidu.com^ADomains^Achuanqisf239baidu^A05/07/2013^A05/07/2013
```

I want to extract words separated by `^A` and write to a CSV file.

For example my output file will like this:

```
missing_feature chuanqisf239baidu.com Domains chuanqisf239baidu
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why only those few words?  There are tons of other ^A's?

Comment: why dont you split on '/\^A/'?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010, that won't work.  For example, if our string is :`() line: 436 Online^Aretired^A`, that'll give use two "words," but we only wanted one...

Comment: @SteveP. and this fact tell us, that your possible solution is broken

Comment: @loldop, merely stating that solely doing that will not accomplish what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can *easily* split on the `^A` field and filter out the data afterwards. I simply took the range of columns that you indicated you were interested in and added some quote logic before joining them with commas.

```
while ( <> ) {
    say join( ',', map { index( $_, ',' ) > -1 ? qq/"$_"/ : $_ } @{[ split /\^A/ ]}[1..5] );
}
```

To break this down into a few more steps it goes like this.

1. I use the "diamond operator" because you shouldn't need me to write your file handling code for you if extracting the data is the main problem. I use it for generic input loop.
2. So we `split` the line like so: `split /\^A/`, which gives us a list.
3. We then take a *slice* of that that list by performing the operation within a slice expression. If you have an array `@a`, `@a[2..4]` is a way to extract only the elements you're interested in. So `@{[ split /\^A/ ]}` is an "array expression", and `@{[ split /\^A/ ]}[1..5]` is a *slice* of that array.
4. But it's a list like any other, so putting it in a `map` expression, we check to see whether it has a comma in the field, if it does we wrap it in double quotes (`qq/"$_"/`) if not we just return it as itself.
5. Then we simply use `join` to insert a comma between each of the fields, and we `say` the resulting string.

*However*, the approach above is poor way to do CSV, it just does it half way. In a real CSV output you have to take care of any possible embedded quotes, should you quote a field.

So with [**`Text::CSV`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV), that's:

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv 
    = Text::CSV->new ( 
        { binary      => 1
        , quote_space => 0 
        } ) 
   or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

while ( <> ) { 
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, [ @{[ split /\^A/ ]}[1..5] ] );
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I'm trying to get better at reading/writing perlish looking perl.

Comment: `split` could take a third argument that limits the number of resulting fragments. → `(split /\^A/, $_, 7)[1..5]` BTW, making an anonymous arrayref, then slicing it is unneccessary: a list can be sliced too.

Comment: @amon, yeah and then you have a element #0 you don't want *and* an element #6 you don't want, you can write `pop @a;shift @a`, but you don't *have* to. Myself, I prefer *expressions* to statements.

Comment: That solution outputs *everything* after the first column, even the empty strings between consecutive `^A`s. It also needs `use feature 'say'`. It puts `undef` values into the list of fields if there are less than five (and so raises warnings if they are enabled), and `@{[ split /\^A/ ]}[1..5]` is better written as `(split /\^A/)[1..5]`. It is also fairly unreadable.

Comment: @Borodin, first of all no it doesn't. It does not emit the two date fields on the end of the record. Second of all, yours misses "Domains" from his "example" (though not comma-delimited). Thirdly, it's a csv file, so columns are important. Fourthly, is the point to write his solution exactly--you guys always say you don't do that--so it's an illustration of the concept: ^A-delimited to comma-delimited output....

Comment: Yes I could have just dumped populated fields out into a csv file, losing *all* positional meaning, just so I can fit some rather ill-defined specs. I chose to preserve the delimited-fields and csv integrity.

Comment: @Axeman: I had misunderstood the problem, and read *"extract words between ^A"* to mean that it was using `^A` as delimiters (i.e. quotes) rather than separators. However my remaining points stand.

Comment: There is also no excuse for `index( $_, ',' ) > -1` instead of a simple `/,/`

Answer (score 1):

This straightforward program seems to do what you need. It expects the name of the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $date = qr|^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\s*$|;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  my @fields = split /\^A/;
  shift @fields;
  pop @fields while $fields[-1] =~ $date;
  print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}
```

If your fields ever contain commas then they need to be quoted, and you should replace the `print` line with this

```
print join(',', map { /,/ ? '"'.s/"/\\"/gr . '"' : $_ } @fields), "\n";
```

which quotes lines containing commas and escapes any quotes those fields may contain.

**output**

```
too_expensive,Money is tight. I would to keep the service but I don&#39;t have the money at this time. Maybe I can come back in the future.,securesanctuary.org,Web Hosting,securesanctuary
too_expensive,Money is tight. I would to keep the service but I don&#39;t have the money at this time. Maybe I can come back in the future.,securesanctuary.org,Web Hosting,securesanctuary
other,Yahoo China service close,lifesig.com,Web Hosting,kennethli2005
other,Yahoo China service close,lifesig.com,Web Hosting,kennethli2005
too_expensive,,securesanctuary.org,Web Hosting,securesanctuary
too_expensive,,securesanctuary.org,Web Hosting,securesanctuary
missing_feature,,chuanqisf244baidu.com,Domains,chuanqisf244baidu
missing_feature,,chuanqisf244baidu.com,Domains,chuanqisf244baidu
retired,,sisterthrifty.com,Domains,trinaboice
retired,,sisterthrifty.com,Domains,trinaboice
missing_feature,,chuanqisf239baidu.com,Domains,chuanqisf239baidu
missing_feature,,chuanqisf239baidu.com,Domains,chuanqisf239baidu
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words;
while (<>) {
    @words = /\^A(.+?)\^A/g and print +( join ',', @words ) . "\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
too_expensive,securesanctuary.org,securesanctuary
other,lifesig.com,kennethli2005
too_expensive,securesanctuary.org,securesanctuary
missing_feature,chuanqisf244baidu.com,chuanqisf244baidu
retired,sisterthrifty.com,trinaboice
missing_feature,chuanqisf239baidu.com,chuanqisf239baidu
```

The script uses a regex to globally capture the text between the `^A`s on each line, and then `join`s those captures with "," before `print`ing the results.

The `and` is used as a [short circuit](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355), so `print`ing occurs only if words have been captured (no blank lines).

Hope this helps!